# Difference between reveal and unfold

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> Reality is revealed/unfolded to us by nature.

"reveal" seems idiomatic here, but could we have a better explanation of why it is better between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both work, but ***unfolded*** is metaphorical. Depending on context and purpose, it can be better to be literal, or to be metaphorical. If you are trying to be understood by as many people as possible, be direct and literal. If you are trying to evoke more than the literal meaning, be poetic and metaphorical.